# I cant seem able to scrape data form a website that is constantly changing its prices using VBA in excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, scrape

I cant seem to find the ID when i inspect the source of the website "rofex.primary.ventures".  All i want to do is grab all the data below the Ult column and put it into an excel worksheet. Ive used firefox because it shows the HTLM code in a nicer way but i would like to scrape it from chrome using an excel Macro. How would i do this?

```
Sub Rofex()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With appIE
.Navigate "https://rofex.primary.ventures"
.Visible = True
End With
Do While appIE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("rx:DO:2019:01:a")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(6).innerHTML

appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing
Range("A1").Value = myValue
End Sub
```

This is what i have but get all types of errors, im new to coding, needless to say. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the available API. There is a csv format xmlhttp response that you can target to extract this info. Note that the results are in 1000s so, for example, `DOEne19` is `ult` `37,960` and the output is `37.96`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://rofex.primary.ventures/api/v1/platform/market/md"
    Dim lines() As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        lines = Split(.responseText, vbLf)
    End With
    Dim output(), i As Long, rowCounter As Long, arr() As String
    ReDim output(1 To UBound(lines), 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(lines)
        If InStr(lines(i), "|") > 0 Then
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            arr = Split(lines(i), "|")
            output(rowCounter, 1) = Replace$(arr(0), "m;", vbNullString)
            output(rowCounter, 2) = arr(6)
        End If
    Next
    output = Application.Transpose(output)
    ReDim Preserve output(1 To 2, 1 To rowCounter)
    output = Application.Transpose(output)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Ticker": .Cells(1, 2) = "1000s"
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)) = output
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Otherwise, you can download as csv as then use loop column A and use split to extract the columns of interest. Download part shown below.

```
Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim http As Object
    Const filepath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestDownload.csv"
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://rofex.primary.ventures/api/v1/platform/market/md", False
    http.send
    On Error GoTo errhand
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .Write http.responseBody
        .SaveToFile filepath '<== specify your path here
        .Close
    End With
    Debug.Print "FileDownloaded"
    TidyFile filepath
    Exit Sub
errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        MsgBox "Download failed"
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub TidyFile(ByVal filepath As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook, lines(), i As Long, output(), rowCounter As Long, arr() As String
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

    With wb.Sheets(1)
        lines = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value)

        ReDim output(1 To UBound(lines), 1 To 2)
        For i = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
            If InStr(lines(i), "|") > 0 Then
                rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
                arr = Split(lines(i), "|")
                output(rowCounter, 1) = Replace$(arr(0), "m;", vbNullString)
                output(rowCounter, 2) = arr(6)
            End If
        Next
        output = Application.Transpose(output)
        ReDim Preserve output(1 To 2, 1 To rowCounter)
        output = Application.Transpose(output)
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Ticker": .Cells(1, 2) = "1000s"
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)) = output
    End With
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, the first one worked like a charm! The second one however came out as "Download Failed", maybe im not inserting the filepath like i should?

Comment: API has changed I think, how can i find the new API of the same webpage that will work for my macro? Debugger highlights ReDim output(1 To UBound(lines), 1 To 2) with error 9. Thanks!

Comment: I’ll have a look

Comment: Use the dev tools in chome (F12) - Network tab. Refresh the page and then look at the XHR requests made and see if the API call is there.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but there are many API's. Ive tried replacing all of them and it still wont work. Thank you so much by the way.

Comment: for example: https://rofex.primary.ventures/api/v2/rofexrt/securities?_ds=1550087701605-993529  but that one produces a json response.

Comment: was there a download button before?

Comment: No, there wasnt a Download button

Comment: If you put that url I just gave in Firefox you should see the Json data

Comment: I replace ""https://rofex.primary.ventures/api/v1/platform/market/md"" with your url and i get an Error 9 and "ReDim output(1 To UBound(lines), 1 To 2)" gets highlighted

Comment: That returns Json. You need to use a jsonparser like jsonconvertor.bas

Comment: Dont know how to use a jsconvertor.bas, if you could code it in i would really appreciate it

Comment: You can find lots of examples of jsonconverter.bas in my previous answers given. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsonconverter.bas+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer

Comment: Im sorry, its been over a month and I still havent been able to code it correctly.  I cant scrape the data from the https://rofex.primary.ventures/ , I dont know if my issue is with the loading page or what.  Any chance of you helping me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to open a new question and include your current code attempt that way more people can look at it and I will also when home.

Comment: I have already downloaded jsconverter.bas and enabled microsoft scripting runtime but my coding skills are very rudimentary

Comment: Yes. I can’t look until tonight.

Comment: Thank you very much, here is the new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600252/i-cant-seem-able-to-scrape-data-off-a-website-that-constantly-changes-its-price