# Save a HTTP request response as CSV in VBA

Tags: vba, csv, http

I'm using the MSXML2.XMLHTTP method to connect to an API via VBA. My preferred response format is in a CSV, but I'm unsure of how to take the `API.responsetext` value and save it as a CSV locally.

Even pasting to a new or existing sheet in the active workbook would be useful.

```
Option Explicit
Sub getData()

Dim API As Object

    Set API = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    API.Open "GET", "https://factsetfundamentals.xignite.com/xFactSetFundamentals.csv/GetFinancialStatements?IdentifierType=Symbol&Identifiers=CSCO&StatementTypes=BalanceSheet,CashFlowStatement&AsOfDate=1/22/2019&ReportType=Annual&ExcludeRestated=False&_token=7C6B46D98F6B4B0C88FF5A5CE2C64C0C", False
    API.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: `API.responsetext` returns response as string.  then read this : https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: It appears that the response is already in CSV format.  You could simple output the result to file in that case: `Open myFile For Output As #1 :
    Print #1, API.responsetext :
    Close #1`

Comment: @cyboashu Thank you, I'm aware of the ability to read the required values from a JSON format, however I'm looking to access the data in CSV format.

Comment: @HMVBA Perfect! I had tried this method but couldn't get it to behave - I was getting CSV files with all the data in a single cell. This method works perfectly. Thanks very much!

Comment: @healey Sounds like you may have been using `Write` instead of `Print`

Comment: you can also do a binary download as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334813/6241235). You wouldn't need the tidy sub.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the suggestion! Does a binary download tend to be more efficient than writing it from text?